# How do I get my images to show up on my readthedocs site using Sphinx?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I am trying to get images to appear on my readthedocs but I cannot figure out why it is not working. I have a file called "images" in my source directory that holds the images I wish to have on the site. In the RST file I use the command:

> .. image:: _images/3DPDG1.png
> :width: 800

This works when I make and run the HTML but when I push to Git and then build on readthedocs this is what shows:

[image: what shows on readthedocs]

When I run the HTML locally this is what shows and what I want to show on the readthedocs:

[image: what I want to show]

Is there a different command I have to use in the RST or is there anything I have to do in conf.py to fix this? I have tried looking for help on this but I could not find anything.

Comment: I would suggest looking at the generated HTML and seeing what changes you can make to access the image resource directly

Comment: some systems may expect images and other elements in special folders - for example `Flask` expect all images/JS/CSS in folder `static` because later it is server directly by web server like Apache/NGINX. OR it may need absolute path which starts with `/`

Comment: Check the RTD build log of your project for errors or warnings. Because the reST you used locally works, it should also work remotely on RTD. My first guess is that you did not commit and push the image to your remote repository, which is from where RTD would get the image. If that is not the issue, then that leaves configuration in `conf.py`, but first verify that the image exists in your remote repository.

Comment: The images exist in the remote repository. What would I have to change in conf.py?